# asp.net mvc view renders incorrect property value for model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a partial view that will not render the correct values for a model.  Both of the lines below fail to render the correct value.  It's as though the view won't refresh.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.customOptionID)
<input type="text" id="customOptionID" value="@Model.customOptionID" />
```

I checked the modelstate before the controller returns the model and it is valid.  I also verified the value was present.

I stepped through the partial view and it also shows the value is present.

I read this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx) but it doesn't seem to apply since the modelstate is valid.

Here is the controller code:

```
'GET: /Item/_editCustomItemChoice
    Public Function _editCustomItemChoice(ByVal customOptionID As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim customOption = db.customOptions.Find(customOptionID)
        If IsNothing(customOption.customItemChoice) Then
            customOption.customItemChoice = New customItemChoice
            customOption.customItemChoice.customOptionID = customOptionID
            customOption.customItemChoice.customOption = customOption
        End If
        Return PartialView("_editCustomItemChoice", customOption.customItemChoice)
    End Function
```

and the model:

```
Public Class customOption

   Public Property customOptionID As Integer

   <Required>
   Public Property Title As String

   <Required>
   Public Property customType As String

   Public Property customItemChoiceID
   Public Overridable Property customItemChoice As customItemChoice
End Class
Public Class customItemChoice

    Public Property customItemChoiceID As Integer

    Public Property choices As String

    Public Property customOptionID As Integer
    <Required>
    Public Overridable Property customOption As customOption

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below link for @Html.HiddenFor extension method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703631%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1